# Scrollbar on a Label

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to be able to scroll text on a label i am using this for the credits portion of a tic tac toe game. How can I make this happen we've only been taught to scroll through number values in the scrollbar not text.

```
 private void xGameCreditsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.xWinnerLabel.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.xCreditsScrollBar.Visible = true;
            this.xWinnerLabel.Text = "This game was made possible with the help of: blah bla blah";
        }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Instead of a Label, use a TextBox and set the `ScrollBars`, `Multiline` and `WordWrap` properties according to your needs. To disable editing of the TextBox (and, thus, make it behave similar to a label), use the [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) property.

Comment: Ok i change it to a text box but I need to implement the scroll bar with out setting them in the properties window how can i do that?

Comment: Every property that you set in the properties window can also be set in code; your question already shows a nice example of setting the `BackColor` and `Text` properties. Just do the same for the properties mentioned in my answer.

Comment: hi i tryed using a textbox for this, but my text newlines dont wrap to a new line when displayed in a textbox but they do in a label.
im not sure why as its an 'Environment.NewLine' but its does so i use the label, but it wont scroll, is there something i can do for this?

Comment: @f1wade: Did you set the MultiLine property to the correct value?

Answer (score 13):

Since there may be a reason to not use a text box (not wanting the text to be selectable and copyable for instance) here is another solution that works for me:

Place a panel in location where you want the label to be, set it's AutoScroll property to true.  Then place the label in the panel, anchor it and set it's AutoSize property to true.  This will make the panel provide the scroll bars if the label's text extends outside of the panel.

You may have to set the MaximumSize for the label if you want the text to only scroll in one direction (set a maximum width size if you want only vertical scrolling or set a maximum height if you want only horizontal scrolling).

Answer (score 7):

A read-only scrollable TextBox control will be much easier to use.

If you really want to use a label, you could put the label inside a scrollable Panel control, and set the label's AutoSize property to true.

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't absolutely have to be a label, you could make this a read-only multi-line edit field instead.  The edit control will scroll automatically.

Comment: it doesn't have to be a label but the scrollbar is a requirement isn't there a way to do this with a label?

Comment: No.  Labels do not have a built-in scrollbar.  If you want to paint only a portion of the label, you'll have to implement the scrolling yourself.  (NOTE: My experience is more with WinForms.  There may be a way to do this in WPF for all I know.)

Comment: Also note that setup a read-only edit control to have no borders, it looks remarkably like a label.