# Using Scroll Bar to Shift Text in a Label

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label that contains a string which is often much larger than the label. I have created another label with no text made to represent a scroll bar, and have set it so that the label moves on the x axis with my mouse as follows:

```
private Point MouseDownLocation;
private void move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void moveX(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (e.X + scrollBar.Left - MouseDownLocation.X > 34 && e.X + scrollBar.Left - MouseDownLocation.X + scrollBar.Width < button1.Location.X - 10)
            {
                scrollBar.Left = e.X + scrollBar.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;                  
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason I have done this is merely for synthetic purposes.
My problem is that I cannot find a way to shift the text within the label to by the amount that the scroll bar has be shifted so that it looks like you are scrolling through the text in the label. Keep in mind that the label cannot be multiline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906581/scrollbar-on-a-label) QA may be helpful

Comment: It is essential that the label is not multiline.

Comment: Set `WordWrap=false`

Comment: There is no WordWrap option for a label. (For synthetic reasons it is ideal that this would be a label and not a textbox) I just want to be able to shift the text a few pixels at a time. Is that at all possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was confused. It does not, in fact, need to be a label, but even with multiline set to ture on my textbox, and WordWrap set to false, it still does not give me a scroll bar.

Comment: In this case, what about putting your label inside a panel with autoscroll?

Comment: No, but I believe I can do it by putting the label in a panel and using my scrollbar to change the location of the label within the panel, without directly worrying about the text. Thank you, sir.